# How to update a Github project from upstream

Tags: git, github

Some months ago I started a new project using [ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) start kit.

I downloaded it to my local machine and I created a new git repository which I pushed to a Github repo.
Now obviously there are many updates on ngx-admin and of course I have many commits and branch in my own repository.

How can I get the new features from the original repo?

Comment: You should have [forked](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) the repo instead of downloading it and creating a repo of your own.

Comment: Is it possibile ti add the original repo as remote and rebase somehow?

Comment: I have not tried it, but you can try adding the original repo as an upstream remote, fetch the remote changes and try to merge it to your local. Worth checking. But better try it on a test repo of your own.